I'm not able to capture traffic that's trying to set up Wi-Fi Direct
I am trying to investigate an issue where one device is having trouble connecting to another device over wifi direct (connection fails from time to time). Those devices run on windows an use wifi direct virtual adapters.
In order to do this I have a separate setup running on kali with a network card that supports monitoring. I am able to observe all traffic between my 2 devices once the connection has been established (monitoring on wifi channel selected for communication, and filtering on MAC addresses of wifi direct virtual adapters).
However I am not able to see any of the traffic that occur before wifi direct connection is successfully established (scan, listen, search/find phases as per wifi direct specification).
I have tried setting my monitoring on channels 1, then 6, then 11 which are supposed to be the 'social' channels as per wifi direct specification (and again filtering on MAC addresses of wifi direct virtual adapters, using wlan.add == MAC_ADDRESS. I repeated that multiple times during different connection attempts but was never able to observe any traffic.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks !
